# Regrowing basil from bought plant

Tags: plant-recommendations, basil, repotting

I bought some basil which came with its roots (in a plastic container, not a pot) I thought it could be a great opportunity to regrow my own basil!

[image: product]

I have seen some videos that show how they take part of the plant and put it first in water, later to put it in a pot.

I’m wondering if having already roots (don’t know if they came ready to repot, maybe they’re dry?) makes it possible to skip the step where the plant is in water.

[image: basil plant]

Maybe I didn’t take the right part of the plant for repotting (I have other parts with leaves)? How long should it be in water? I’ve seen some answers to problems where they state that the basil may have too much sun or too much water (or not enough). So I also wonder in what conditions should I take care of the basil...

Thanks!

Comment: If the container was sealed when you bought it, as soon as you open it the plants will start to lose water, and will soon die. So you need to do *something* to let them take up water. Putting them in a glass of water is fine as a "life support system" for a few hours until you plant them properly. It's certainly better than just leaving them to wilt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got roots with dirt on them you know they've been grown in soil rather than hydroponically. So just separate them into individual plants and pot them into potting mix. They will need to be kept in the shade or inside to help recovery from transplant shock.

If you want to take a cutting and root them, take a stem without roots and try growing in water.

Comment: How does basil (or other plants) work in paper cups? It’s a cheap way to plant :)

Comment: @PichiWuana it works well for basil, just ensure that there are drainage holes (or water it super-carefully).